# Is anyone using Entity Framework with an Oracle database?

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework

I am wondering if anyone is already using Entity Framework with an Oracle database in a production environment? There seems to be no support for EF in ODP.Net and only 3rd party data providers (OraDirect) seem to be available to connect with Oracle. Someone mentioned asample data provider available on Codeplex but it is presented with the message that it should never be used in a production environment.

Are you using EF with an Oracle database already?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I wouldn't attempt this yet. The message on the sample data provider is warning enough. The level of validation you would need to go through to be comfortable using EF in this configuration wouldn't be worth the effort, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed this from Oracle

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html

The only problem i have accoured is when i have a table with a SEQ+Trigger to have "auto ident" field, the framework doesn't return the number on "SaveChanges()" when i adds a contextobject. But the record itself gets inserted fine.

Otherwise it seems ok.

The app i'm doing is only to be used internaly in the company. But as the companys main system is Microsoft XAL on Oracle, there proberly will be more apps done this way. So ofcourse hope for a stable realease soon.

\T